# Are there any good guides on custom Cocoa User Interface Design?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, interface

I've been a software developer (mainly Visual Studio) for many years and have been working with Objective C and Cocoa for some months now. I have a good handle now on the language and the frameworks but one thing I need to work on is interface design, more specifically custom views and tables.

There is a lot of info out there on standard design but not much on the custom designs. Here's an example of what I want to do. Create a table view with multiple information (text fields and images) per cell and have that cell expand showing more information when clicked on.

Are there any books, tutorials, walkthroughs, etc that you would recommend to learn this part of the process?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For design topics, Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGIntro/XHIGIntro.html) are a great place to start.

For implementation issues, have a look at [Control and Cell Programming Topics For Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ControlCell/ControlCell.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000015i). As the title implies, it goes into detail about how controls & cells work together, including how to subclass one or both to implement custom UIs. Also interesting are the [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978), the [Cocoa Drawing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290), the [Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514), and the [Core Animation Cookbook](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_Cookbook/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005406).

Comment: I have been through the HIG and it does a great job of telling us what to do but not so much how to do it. What I'm looking for is more along the lines of books, sites etc that would contain walkthroughs for this type of thing much like the walkthroughs at cocoadevcentral.

Comment: OK, but you asked about design - not implementation. :-) I've added another link above, that talks more about the latter.

Comment: IIRC there’s a WWDC 2010 presentation on how to design custom views.

Comment: Cocoa With Love sometimes features posts about custom UI: http://cocoawithlove.com/

Comment: @Bavarious - Great link! Added to my feed reader.

Comment: Thanks for the links. More learning which is alway good